# List of Models for auto.arima function

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am using the `forecast` package in R and I want to know what the list of models are that the `auto.arima` function is going through in order to decide which ARIMA model fits best. Is there a way I can extract a list of all the models being tested to ensure it wasn't missing anything or so that it isn't so much of a blackbox?

Here is an example:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
fit

Series: WWWusage 
ARIMA(1,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1     ma1
      0.6504  0.5256
s.e.  0.0842  0.0896

sigma^2 estimated as 9.995:  log likelihood=-254.15
AIC=514.3   AICc=514.55   BIC=522.08



plot(forecast(fit,h=20))
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Use `trace=TRUE` when you call `auto.arima`.

Comment: Hi Dr. Hyndman, that worked great. Thank you. And I also added `Stepwise = FALSE` to add more options based on your DataCamp course and articles posted.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7) and [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v27/i03/paper) for documentation/explanation on the auto.arima() algorithm.